# pybind11: Access violation, no RTTI data, when casting void* to pointer to previously registered class and returning it to python

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am running into an issue where I try to cast a `void*` to a pointer to a previously registered class `MtDTI<MtObject>*`, and returning that pointer to the python side. The function is a simple wrapper function, that only casts the pointer like such:

```cpp
m.def("to_mt_dti", [](void* obj) {
    return static_cast<MtDTI<MtObject>*>(obj);
}, py::return_value_policy::reference);
```

However when I try to run the following code in Python:

```py
dti = test.to_mt_dti(obj) # test is the pybind11 module
```

I get an exception saying `RuntimeError: Access violation - no RTTI data!`, stemming from that line.

For reference, the `obj` variable is a `void*` that was previously passed to Python from the C++ side, and is a pointer to static memory, which is why I also specify `py::return_value_policy::reference`, to make sure Python doesn't try to deallocate it once it goes out of scope.

The class is registered like so:

```cpp
py::class_<MtDTI<MtObject>>(m, "MtDTI")
    .def(py::init([](MtDTI<MtObject>* obj) { return obj; }), py::return_value_policy::reference)
    .def(py::init([](void* obj) { return static_cast<MtDTI<MtObject>*>(obj); }), py::return_value_policy::reference)
    // And some more general member functions
```

As you can see the class has a constructor defined for both `MtDTI<MtObject>*` as well as `void*` directly. As far as I'm aware, pybind11 should be able to auto-convert from pointer to the class if that class has been registered before.

I am working in Visual Studio 2022 17.1.1, Using Python 3.9.5 with pybind11 Version 2.9.1.
I should also mention that this is an embedded module, and the Python code is run using `py::eval_file`.